# Connection to SQL server suddenly stopped working

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, connection-string

I had it working before. Only change I did is exporting database by generating script and importing it in server.

Web server: IIS / ASP.NET web app 
Connection string:

```
  <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=SERVER; 
Initial Catalog=tkl;Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=tkl;Password=PASS; Connection Lifetime=150; 
Connect Timeout=150; Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=20;Max Pool Size=500" />
```

Error:

```
  2020-09-27 05:23:44.6361|ERROR|System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 
Cannot open database "tkl" requested by the login. The login failed.
    Login failed for user 'tkl'.
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
```

User 'tkl' exists in both TKL database and on SQL Server .
I am not sure what is wrong here. probably I need to set some permissions. **Any help is appreciated.**

**Update:**

SQL Log:

> Login failed for user 'tkl'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'tkl'. [CLIENT: ]

Both windows and SQL authentificaiton are enabled.
I can try to post 'tkl' user object permissions as well.

Comment: Look at the logs on the SQL Server and find the *real* authentication error. If you don't understand it, then post that in your question as an [edit].

Comment: If you dropped and recreated all of the objects in the database, including the `tkl` database user, it likely isn't linked to the corresponding `tkl` SQL Login.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning raises a good point. Is the `USER` object `tkl` in your database linked to the `LOGIN` server object `tkl`?

Comment: actuall username is tkl , same as db name.
What exact permissions i need to have for user tkl to access the database ?

Comment: @Jalle please get the error from the logs, that will tell us exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error is telling you that the `LOGIN` does not have access to the database you are trying to connect to. Just because a database has a `USER` with the same name as the name of a `LOGIN` on the server, does not mean that that `LOGIN` has access to the database.

`USER` objects are mapped to `LOGIN` objects via the SID, *not* the name. This means you could have 2 objects, with the different names mapped to each other, and 2 objects with the same name *not* mapped to each other.

Most likely, here, you just need to `ALTER` the `USER` to correct the mapping:

```sql
USE YourDatabase;
GO

ALTER USER tkl WITH LOGIN = tkl;
```

Comment: I just ran that command and it run succesfuly.
Yet, when i run the app it still has the error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "tkl" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'tkl'.

Comment: Then either that command didn't run successfully, or you ran it in the wrong database. If you're still being told that you can't open the explicit database.

Comment: Finally I fixed problem by granting all possible permission to user on server level

Comment: Rather than all possible permissions, you could be giving it the **minimal** amount of permissions it needs to complete the role(s) it needs to fulfil, @Jalle .